# i need to get Last child of my firebase databse

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i want to get last child  from my firebase data structure  in which i only know the reference of received and first child of it 
[image]

i try this one but it will  return all child but i need only last one that use in query limiTolast(1) like this

```
  DatabaseReference users = mDatabase.child("received");
      //  DatabaseReference receiver = users.child(firebaseUser.getUid());
        final DatabaseReference receiver = 
    users.child("GTjrWgpKjoeXUt4JdBJTYP1JkVT2");

        receiver.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                Log.d(TAG, "key count=" + postSnapshot.getKey());

                for (DataSnapshot sender: postSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    Log.d(TAG, "sender key count=" + sender.getKey());

                }

            }


        }


        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.e("SHAN " ,databaseError.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

Comment: vist [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Read in the entire node fnB0M (by value), add the elements to an array. The last item in the array is the one you want. Or query that node for a child contained in the last element. Or, add a child to each node; isLast: false and make it isLast: true for the last one, then query by that. Or, as you mentioned use limitToLast - making sure to read in the correct parent node, which would be the fnB0M one, not the GTjr node.

Answer (score 11):

If you know the complete path of the parent node (`received/GTjrWgpKjoeXUt4JdBJTYP1JkVT2/fnBOM...`), you can get only the last child node under that location with `limitToLast(1)`:

```
DatabaseReference ref = users.child("GTjrWgpKjoeXUt4JdBJTYP1JkVT2/fnBOM...`");
ref.orderByKey().limitToLast(1).addChildEventListener(...
```

If you don't know the complete path to the parent node, there is no way to retrieve a subset of the child nodes.

Comment: yeah i don't know the complete path of parent node

Answer (score 4):

You can use a query with the 'limitToLast' method that returns a specified number of items beginning from the last.

`Query query=datasnapshot.child("childname").orderByKey().limitToLast(1);`

Comment: there is a typo, is `.limitToLast(1)` (be aware of case sensitivity)

Answer (score 2):

It is a best solution to find the last exit child from firebase

```
 String LASTMESSAGE=NULL; DatabaseReference dbref =
 Firebase.getInstance().getReference(); Query lastchield =
 FirebaseDatabase.child("yourchieldfororder")
                           .orderByKey().limitToLast(1); lastchield.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
     @Override
     public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot ds) {
          LASTMESSAGE= ds.child("message").getValue().toString();
     }
     @Override
     public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
         LASTMESSAGE = "No-Last-MESSAGE-EXIT";
     } });`
```

Query first order the child id then give you the last id of the child in data- snapshot.

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

Your reference is not correct your receiver databaseReference should point to fnBOM..... instead of "GTjrWgpKjoeXUt4JdBJTYP1JkVT2"

```
       final DatabaseReference receiver = 
       users.child("GTjrWgpKjoeXUt4JdBJTYP1JkVT2").child("fnBom...");
```

and your can store each child on an arraylist and the access last element from 
   arraylist by

```
        myArrayList.get(myArrayList.size()-1);
```

Comment: Which data do you want to retrieve exactly ??

Comment: the last node of fnBom.... and i'm not exactly know the fnbpm.. name because there is multiple child of GTjrwg.... including fnBom so i need only last node

Comment: and my solution doesn't help you because ?

Comment: nope because .child("fnBom..."); this one  is come run time from loop

Comment: Ok so you have a array of string with values like fnBom which are child of GTjr... right ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142334/discussion-between-muhammad-shan-and-dwijraj-bhattacharyya).

Answer (score 0):

finally i  make the logic for getting last node even we don't know the exact reference of our child

**solution**

In my scenario there are three parent

1. received (The root node)
2. the user GTjr..... ( i just know the reference only this point )
3. and the third node fnBom... (actually problem in this i need to get last child of this array )

so i get the total ChilderenCount of (fnBom.. node) in my case it is 5 , now i used for loop and match it with if condition to get last nod by this

```
if(loopCount==childrenCount){

 // here we can get the last child 

}
```

thanks for all of you people  :)

Comment: This is bad solution ever, really you get all the list then you choose one of them.. You should change your database structure.