# Get last child for each child using Firebase Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get `sender_uid` values on the image below:

[image]

This is my code below. I don't get any values with it, and I don't know why. Can someone explain what is wrong with the code? Thanks!

EDIT: I only want the **last** *sender_uid* for each parent - for example:

- for node `391rfBEXjVUplEW8aoahMtluSmz1_6dTv7oHnWOh55XzRuf9ouZFZkGt2`
     I need only *sender_uid* from *LJxvDjdetWz1-DAFVCy*, **NOT** from *LJxvA65WA7MX8aaX5nF*.

  ```
  mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
          @Override
          public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
              List<UsersListGetter> usersList = new ArrayList<>();
              recyclerView.setAdapter(new UsersListAdapter(usersList, getApplicationContext()));

              recyclerView.setAdapter(new UsersListAdapter(null, getApplicationContext()));

              for (DataSnapshot ch : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                  String senderReceiver[] = ch.getKey().split("_");

                  if (senderReceiver[0].equals(mAuth.getUid()) || senderReceiver[1].equals(mAuth.getUid())) {
                      Query lastQuery = mDatabase.child(ch.getKey()).orderByKey().limitToLast(1);
                      lastQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                          @Override
                          public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                              String message = dataSnapshot.child("message_body").getValue().toString();
                              Log.d("MSG", message);
                          }

                          @Override
                          public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                              //Handle possible errors.
                          }
                      });
                  }
              }
          }

      @Override
      public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

      }
  });
  ```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [i need to get Last child of my firebase databse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43557122/i-need-to-get-last-child-of-my-firebase-databse)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way to get the sender_uid from each node

First create a pojo class to get your desired data

```
public class UserPojo {

    private String sender_uid;

    public UserPojo() {

    }

    public String getSender_uid() {
        return sender_uid;
    }

    public void setSender_uid(String sender_uid) {
        this.sender_uid = sender_uid;
    }
}
```

and then just retrieve it for each chat ref

```
mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                List<UsersListGetter> usersList = new ArrayList<>();
                recyclerView.setAdapter(new UsersListAdapter(usersList, getApplicationContext()));

                recyclerView.setAdapter(new UsersListAdapter(null, getApplicationContext()));

                for (DataSnapshot ch : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                  UserPojo up = ch.getValue(UserPojo.class);
                  String senderUid = up.getSender_uid(); //here you got your sender_uid

                        Query lastQuery = mDatabase.child(ch.getKey()).orderByKey().limitToLast(1);
                        lastQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                String message = dataSnapshot.child("message_body").getValue().toString();
                                Log.d("MSG", message);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                                //Handle possible errors.
                            }
                        });

                }
            }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for response! I forgot to mention - is it possible to get only **last** *sender_uid*  for each parent?

Comment: you can try with orderByChild("sender_uid").limitToLast(1)

Comment: Hmm, I got zero results with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `chat` node is a direct child of your Firebase root, to solve this, please use the following query:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query query = rootRef
    .child("chat")
    .child(receiver_id + "_" + sender_uid)
    .orderByChild("sender_uid")
    .limitToLast(1);
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(/* ... */);
```